# Gulp - how to discover a relative path depth?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I have a project in a single repository that is supposed to have core files in the root folder, that are used in entire project, and separate theme folders that have their own unique settings and build processes.

Project looks like this:

```
core/
themes/
   some/long/folder/for/a/theme/root/
       theme-folders/
       gulpfile.js
   another/theme/folder/root/
       theme-folders/
       gulpfile.js
config.json
```

Each theme folder has it's own gulpfile.js. When I want to initiate gulp process, I start it from desired theme folder.

Gulp and gulp plugins that I use work fine only with relative paths and it is out of the question to use absolute paths. It is problematic to manually discover directory depth for relative paths and I would like instead to automate this process.

Question is - How do I discover directory depth from one gulpfile.js to project root, where config.json is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Mark's answer, I have made my own solution. There is a plugin to determine root folder for the app and it is called `app-root-path`.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const path = require('path');
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');

gulp.task('default', function () {

 // Function to calculate directory depth
 const dirDepth = (myDir) => {
  return myDir.split(path.sep).length;
 };

 console.log('Current directory = ' + __dirname);
 console.log('Root direcotry = ' + appRoot.path);
 console.log('Depth difference = ' + (dirDepth(__dirname) - dirDepth(appRoot.path)));

 var rel = '..' + path.sep;
 var depth = dirDepth(__dirname) - dirDepth(appRoot.path);
 var relPath = rel.repeat(depth);

 console.log('Relative path from current folder to root is: ' + relPath);

 var pkg = require(relPath + 'package.json');

 console.log('Test to see if it works: ' + pkg.name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help. Using this folder structure:

```
pathRelative  (the repository level)

├───core 
└───themes
    ├───a
│       └───b
│           └───c
│               └───d
│                   └───root
│                       └───theme-folders
    └───h
        └───i
            └───j
                └───root
                    └───theme-folders

const gulp = require('gulp');
const path = require('path');

// set the repository path
// I couldn't figure out a way to retrieve this programmatically

let cwdRoot = "C:\\Users\\Mark\\OneDrive\\Test Bed\\pathRelative"

gulp.task('default', function () {

  // get full path to current working root folder
  // fullPath = C:\Users\Mark\OneDrive\Test Bed\pathRelative\themes\a\b\c\d\root

  let fullPath = path.resolve();
  console.log("fullPath = " + fullPath);

  // get folders from the cwdRoot to the current working folder
  //  folders = pathRelative\themes\a\b\c\d\root

  let folders = path.relative( cwdRoot, fullPath );
  console.log("folders = " + folders);

  let folderDepth = folders.split(path.sep).length;
  console.log(folderDepth);

  // 6 for the themes/a/b/c/d/root
  // 5 for the themes/h/i/j/root
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, it didn't quite solved my problem, but you gave me an idea on how to solve it. One note - path.resolve() didn't work nicely on windows with symbolic links.